# Related to Particle in Box

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, potential, schroedinger-equation

Let us suppose there is an particle in a 3D box, it is in some energy state, say in ground state. Now at suddenly I change the size of the box to something else, say I increased the length of side. Now energy levels are different from before, suppose they are such that any state energy is not equals to ground state energy of box before. What will happen?

You can take quantitative data.

Comment: You basically have to solve again for the new boundary, with the initial wave function being the one of the initial box. But if the change happens slowly it is known that the particle will not change energy levels, this is known as the adiabatic theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The state of the particle, which was previously a single energy eigenstate of the old box, is now equal to some superposition of the different energy eigenstates of the new box. If you now measure the energy, you can get various values for the energy, with various probabilities, as determined by that superposition.

Comment: Can you please Show me how I can do this?

Comment: No, because it is against the policy of this site to provide solutions to homework-like problems, and this is a standard homework problem in a QM course.